# Qual a origem da expressão "um pé-rapado"? Podemos usá-la para o gênero feminino?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

O [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/p%C3%A9-rapado) define **"pé-rapado"** como "pessoa de condição humilde, sem recursos".

- Literalmente, o que significaria "pé rapado"?
- Qual a origem dessa expressão?
- Em pt-BR é uma expressão bem conhecida. É também de uso corrente em pt-PT?
- Pode-se usá-la para qualificar o gênero feminino, chamando uma mulher de "um pé-rapado"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Literalmente, o que significaria "pé rapado"?
> - Qual a origem dessa expressão?

Duas explicações (e significados) que frequentemente se encontram são que pessoas pobres:

1. não andariam de carruagem ou mesmo a cavalo, e sujariam portanto seus sapatos ou pés, tendo que usar "limpa-pés" (raspadores de lama, como na foto abaixo) antes de entrar num prédio ou local público - assim, "pé rapado" significaria "**pé rapado de lama**";

[image]

2. simplesmente não teriam sapatos e, portanto, "pé-rapado" significaria "**descalço**".

O uso da expressão com o sentido (2) [remontaria](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/proverbios/perapado.php) ao período colonial:

> já aparece [nos versos](https://www.literaturabrasileira.ufsc.br/documentos/?action=download&id=75825#-1) que Gregório de Matos dedicou a uma mulata baiana que lhe havia pedido um cruzado para consertar os sapatos, na segunda metade do século XVII:
>
> "*Se tens o cruzado, Anica,
>
>   Manda tirar os sapatos,
>
>   E senão lembra-te o tempo
>
>   Que andaste de pé rapado.*"

José de Alencar, em seu livro [Guerra dos mascates (vol. 2, Cap. 2)](https://digital.bbm.usp.br/handle/bbm/4671) conta:

> Retaliaram os do Recife com a alcunha de *pés-rapados* que puzeram aos naturaes [*nobres*], não só pela circunstancia de andarem elles descalços e á ligeira, com o que se desembaraçavam no manejo das armas e na celeridade da marcha entre o mato fechado, como por allusão á estreiteza de muitos fidalgos cahidos em completa penuria.

Confirmando o sentido de "descalço" para a expressão, mas também deixando claro que a expressão já existia com o significado de "pobre" no século XVIII (o romance é 1870, mas a Guerra dos Mascates passou-se nos anos 1770-1771).

Não encontrei fonte história para o sentido (1) (do limpa-pés) acima.

> - Pode-se usá-la para qualificar o gênero feminino, chamando uma mulher de "um pé-rapado"?

Sim. Os dicionários definem a expressão em termos de "pessoa", não de "homem", e certamente já ouvi "pé-rapado" ser empregado para se referir a mulheres.

> - Em pt-BR é uma expressão bem conhecida. É também de uso corrente em pt-PT?

Dicionários portugueses também contém a expressão, sem marcar como brasileira, então creio que se usa também em Portugal. Aliás, lá também aparentemente se usa [pés-descalços](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/p%C3%A9-descal%C3%A7o) com o significado de "indivíduo extremamente pobre", o que reforça a origem (2) da expressão.